# Cannot generate bibliography:"I found no \citation command"

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

There are many related questions but I couldn't solve it from them.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{Moran05,
author = {T. Moran},
journal = {Sociological Forum},
number = {2},
pages = {209-244},
publisher = {Wiley, Springer},
title = {Text},
volume = {20},
year = {2005}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{test}

\begin{document}

\textcite{Moran05}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I get:

```
Process started: bibtex.exe "test"

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2016/W32TeX)
The top-level auxiliary file: test.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file test.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file test.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file test.aux
(There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

Comment: Why BibTeX? Use biber: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Comment: That just crashed TexStudio... nice

Comment: Well then, restart.

Comment: Now it works. Thanks! **But**, I have been using `bibtex` for other documents this morning, without any problem. It is just this one that fails. Not clear why.

Comment: Because you *explicitely* say, that `biber` should be used. `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}` `biber` is the alternative to `BibTeX`.

Comment: I see now. Yep, that is the sole difference. Hope will not forget that from now on. Make it an answer maybe?